# だって at the end of sentence

Tags: grammar, quotes

I have stumbled upon this sentence during my immersion あのオヤジを呼ぶだって?
What does だって mean at the end of the sentence?

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24481/i-adjective-followed-by-%e3%81%a0/24483#24483