# だ in 「別に迷惑だなんて」

Tags: grammar, copula

> 別に迷惑**だ**なんて

What kind of difference in meaning or nuances does this だ impart to such an utterance?

Examples with だ:

> 電車から車椅子が降りる時や、車椅子が階段昇降機を使う時に、駅員さんの「ご迷惑をおかけしまーす」という掛け声が聞こえてくるけど、別に迷惑だなんて思ってないから、「ご協力お願いしまーす」程度にしてもらった方がいいかなーて。自分が通る度に「迷惑」て言われたくないだろうなーと思いました。([source](https://twitter.com/mugi1208/status/946166378561540096))

> 「それはもちろん……私のせいで九条さんに迷惑をかけてしまったからです」
> 　彼女の表情はやけに暗かった。
> 　後半になるほど小さくなっていくその声に、焦りや恐怖といった感情が含まれているのを感じる。
> 「別に迷惑だなんて思ってない」([source](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/1177354054897357912/episodes/1177354055114003960))

> 「今日は、色々迷惑かけてごめんね。」
> 最後、と思って傾けても何も出なかったので全部飲んだことを悟り缶を握り潰す。
> 見たらお姫様の顔はまた先程のように何かを考えているようだ。
> ……どうしたんだ？
> 『別に、迷惑だなんて思ってないよ。』([source](https://www.berrys-cafe.jp/pc/book/n1493514/199/))

> 「おはようございます。一か月、迷惑かけてすみませんでした……って、あれ、真瀬さん一人？」
> 栞が声をかけると、資料に埋もれていた遥が顔を上げた。
> 目の下にはくっきりとクマができている。
> 「ああ、別に迷惑だなんて思ってないから気にするな」([source](https://www.berrys-cafe.jp/pc/book/n1477227/35/))

> 「謝るな」
> 「だって……お兄ちゃんに迷惑かけちゃったから」
> 「……別に、迷惑だなんて言ってない」([source](https://www.alphapolis.co.jp/novel/143044857/821597506/episode/5366018))

> どうしてそんなに泣きそうな顔するの…？別に迷惑だなんて思ってない。([source](https://www.alphapolis.co.jp/novel/626198736/959213939/episode/3783455))

だ-less examples:

> 「あ、あと別に迷惑なんて思ってないからね！むしろこっちが……」([source](https://twitter.com/atchley371/status/755964788941975552))

> 別に迷惑なんてかかってませんぜ([source](https://twitter.com/Ideal_DRAQUE/status/1240087004911550465))

> 別に迷惑なんて思ってねぇのによ。まぁ、一つ迷惑としたら、お前が来ない事だ。([source](https://commu.nosv.org/bbs/haruki/1215650))

> 別に迷惑なんてことはありませんよ([source](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13207348378))

> あ、昨日はお疲れさまでした。私は別に迷惑なんてかかってないですよ　DPSですし・・・([source](https://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/character/5253941/blog/1245252/?order=2))

> 「海星君、ごめん。何か色々迷惑かけちゃって」
> 「別に迷惑なんてかけられてねぇよ。つーか……――」([source](https://www.berrys-cafe.jp/pc/book/n1076137/189/))

> 「ごめんごめん。手料理のときと同じ、ふとした思い付きで誘っただけだからさ。迷惑なら断ってくれていいんだ」
> 「別に迷惑なんて言ってません！」([source](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n5484hl/41/))

> 別に迷惑なんて思わんから今度からちゃんと言いや。大先生だけじゃ頼りないやろ？([source](https://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=16048103))

> 「修羅が俺に迷惑を掛けたく無いと思ってくれるのは嬉しいが、俺は修羅の主であり親だ、別に迷惑なんて幾らでも掛けて良いし、頼ってくれるとこっちも嬉しいんだぜ」([source](https://www.alphapolis.co.jp/novel/445327961/327270578/episode/2063960))

The だ version feels more like a quote, either a thought or an utterance? It feels a little bit like that because I guess I can't say 別に迷惑**だ**なんてかかってません or 別に迷惑**だ**なんてことはありませんよ, can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of だ has been explained in previous questions. In short, it expresses the speaker's surprise or disagreement.

- [~たいだとか why is there a だ here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60014/5010)
- [Is 「３人いるだと」 grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5693/5010)
- [i-adjective followed by だ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24481/5010)

This type of だ/です comes right after a predicate in 終止形. You cannot put だ when 迷惑 is used as a subject (e.g., 迷惑なんてかかってない) or an object (e.g., 迷惑なんてかけてない). When 迷惑 is used as a predicate, 迷惑なんて and 迷惑だなんて are interchangeable because なんて already has a nuance similar to だ, but I feel the sentence sounds more emphatic with だ.

**EDIT**: 迷惑 is a na-adjective, and thus can take だ without the nuance mentioned above (e.g. 迷惑だと思っていませんか?). Still, the combination of だなんて typically has a surprised nuance regardless of the word class of the preceding predicate.